# Configure the landing page after SSO authentication

Tags: spring-security

I want to know how to setup the relay state with the new saml library. Basically once I am authenticated via the asserting party, I want to have a relay state url (a JSP in my application), where I should land. In the saml extensions library, as far as I know, the relay state url was set in the SAMLMessageContext object.

**Actual Behaviour** The mechanism of setting the page where I would be redirected to after SAML login has changed. I am not sure how to set the desired JSP where I want to land in the new library.

**Expected behavior** After the successful call to the assertionConsumerServiceLocation in my application, I should be taken to a Url configured by me (Relaystate). I need help in configuring this URL.

I tried to set up the relay state like this :-

```
Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequestResolver(
        RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver registrations) {
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver authenticationRequests =
            new OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver(registrations);
    authenticationRequests.setRelayStateResolver(relayStateResolver);
    return authenticationRequests;
}
```

I have defined the relayStateResolver like the following :-

`private Converter<HttpServletRequest, String> relayStateResolver = (request) -> "my_desired_jsp_url_string";`

Are my above configurations correct, and would they help me in landing on the desired JSP page after successful login?

Currently, below is the error I am facing with the above implementation. I am working to fix that (I need to get the Opensaml4 from Shibboleth's repository of artifacts), but wanted to know if the above configuration is correct before making that fixing effort.

> Jan 03, 2023 5:54:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
> invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context
> with path [/company] threw exception [Filter execution threw an
> exception] with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.opensaml.saml.saml2.core.AuthnRequest.setIssueInstant(Ljava/time/Instant;)V
> at
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.lambda$resolve$1(OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.java:60)
> at
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver.resolve(OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestResolver.java:133)
> at
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.resolve(OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.java:59)
> at
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:184)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)

Comment: Please separate the stack trace into a separate question as it is unrelated. Likely, the stack trace is due to a mismatch in your pom regarding the Spring Security and OpenSAML dependencies. In the separate question, seeing you OpenSAML and Spring Security pom declarations or the relevant output of `dependency-tree` will help.

Answer (score 1):

Because `RelayState` can be used for several things and is not always used to describe the post-login redirect URL (the spec says `MAY`), it is not defaulted to do this.

You can configure Spring Security to redirect to the `RelayState` parameter by configuring a `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` like so:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain appEndpoints(HttpSecurity http) {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler =
        new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter(Saml2ParameterNames.RELAY_STATE);

    http
        .saml2Login((saml2) -> saml2
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler)
            // ...
        )
        // ...

    return http.build();
}
```

You will also need to configure the relay state resolver, as you have already shown in your post.